# Dealloc called but live memory not decreasing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, profiler

I have three `UIViewControllers` and all of their dealloc methods are called whenever I dismiss them. This is exactly what I want to happen so that the memory won't balloon up.

However, when I ran the Profile to test the memory usage and for some leakages, I noticed that even if the dealloc was called, the live memory doesn't decrease somehow. What's more is that it keeps on increasing whenever I switch from one `UIViewController` to another (which is expected by the way). Sometimes it will decrease, but only a few memory will be decreased.

I am sure that the dealloc methods of each `UIViewControllers` were called since I put a log inside of the methods. Also, no there are no leakages recorded when I used Profile.

So can anyone explain why the memory does not decrease at all?

Comment: Hope you are calling [super dealloc]; in your dealloc methods.. I don't think anyone can help you further without seeing your code...

Comment: Even if `dealloc` was called, that doesn't mean that your memory will be released immediately. It depends on autorelease cycle and your implementation.

Comment: I just realized that. It the memory slowly decreases, as if the allocated memories are not released all at once.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else said, without seeing your code is a bit hard to figure out what's going. So instead I will leave you [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/08/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html) & [this](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) articles about analysing the heap using instruments.